# How do I remove lines that are repeating and contains certain words from text file?

Tags: python, selenium, twitter

I'm trying to remove repeated lines and lines containing certain words from scraped data. I searched for various codes but they are not working :(

This is the code. Only the first part works, that removes repeating lines:

```
openFile = open("links.txt", "r") 
writeFile = open("updatedfile.txt", "w") 
#Store traversed lines
tmp = set() 
for txtLine in openFile: 
#Check new line
    if txtLine not in tmp: 
        writeFile.write(txtLine) 
#Add new traversed line to tmp 
        tmp.add(txtLine)         
openFile.close() 
writeFile.close()

sleep(5)

with open("updatedfile.txt", "r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

with open("updatedfile.txt", "w") as fp:
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip("\n") != "search":
            fp.write(line)
```

This is the links.txt file

```
https://twitter.com/search?q=%23BTC&src=hashtag_click
https://twitter.com/search?q=%23ADA&src=hashtag_click
https://twitter.com/search?q=%23LTC&src=hashtag_click
https://twitter.com/search?q=%23CAKE&src=hashtag_click
https://twitter.com/Marie62943337
https://twitter.com/Marie62943337
https://twitter.com/Fathur0501
https://twitter.com/Fathur0501
https://twitter.com/BogdanMar93
https://twitter.com/BogdanMar93
https://t.[spaced because body cannot contain short url]co/74ZzkVwa2W
https://t. co/Gv2tyiWfAk
```

I want the output to be:

```
https://twitter.com/Marie62943337
https://twitter.com/Fathur0501
https://twitter.com/BogdanMar93
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this code. I think it works

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()
fp.close()

unique = set() 

with open("test.txt", "w") as fp:
    for line in lines:
        if "search" not in line and line not in unique and "twitter.com" in line:
            fp.write(line)
            unique.add(line)
```

Please share the query in the comment below.

Comment: It worked. I also need to remove "https://t. co/Gv2tyiWfAk" from lines. How do I do that?

Comment: You can add a condition that it must contain the word twitter.com. I have updated the code, you can refer to. And don't forget to mark the right answer part as it can be used for future reference.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Everything's smooth now.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to use this, with 'in':

```
lines = ['https://twitter.com/search?q=%23CAKE&src=hashtag_click', 'https://twitter.com/Marie62943337']
for line in lines:
    if 'search' not in line:
        print(line)
```

Comment: I just want to remove lines that contains "search" and "t.co".

Comment: To do that, you can expand the condition like:
    `if 'search' not in line and 't.co' not in line: `

Comment: Thank you. I checked this works too. Something new to learn every day!